# Create query to count all elements that doesn't have some value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with elements like

```
{
    "elementName" : "abc",
    ...
}
```

i was getting the count of this just like `Element.count()`, and it was cool
but now, i have an array of names that i don't want to be in that count, for example
`["abc", "aaa"]`

so, i could just do something like

```
const namesToExclude = ["abc", "aaa"];
const elements = Element.find();
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (!namesToExclude.includes(elements[i].elementName)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

or by any other ways to do this

anyway, my question is, can i do that all with a `.count({<query here>})` ?
if so, what is the query i should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Element.count({elementName: {$nin: namesToExclude }})
```